# query all contacts in ContentResolver resolved in ANR

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I encountered in an annoying bug, that happens only on Nexus 4. Everytime, when I'm going through all the contacts of the device I'm getting ANR. Obviously, first thing that I did is to go through the traces.txt in order to find if there were deadlock or starvation and there weren't.

Here is how I'm using the ContentResolver:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION_NAMES, WHERE_NAMES, new String[] { contact.getPhoneBookId() }, null);
```

Here is the top 5 threads that were registered:

```
JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=480
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415f0ca8 self=0x4152a408

  | sysTid=25870 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074544980
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1610 stm=187 core=1
  #00  pc 00020588  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002cb37  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d3ed  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001d8d7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+42)
  #04  pc 0001dadf  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+118)
  #05  pc 00019791  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+30)
  #06  pc 00071121  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #07  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #08  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #09  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #10  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #11  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #12  pc 00060861  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
  #13  pc 000687c3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #14  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #15  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #16  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #17  pc 0006057d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #18  pc 00049d0b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #19  pc 0004d2b3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #20  pc 0004dfd7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
  #21  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
  #22  pc 0000e34b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
  #23  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:411)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
  at com.myapp.contacts.PhoneBookUtils.populateNames(PhoneBookUtils.java:346)
  at com.myapp.contacts.PhoneBookUtils.getPhoneBookContact(PhoneBookUtils.java:217)
  at com.myapp.contacts.PhoneBookUtils.populateLists(PhoneBookUtils.java:184)
  at com.myapp.contacts.PhoneBookUtils.getPhoneBookContacts(PhoneBookUtils.java:150)
  at com.myapp.contacts.PhoneBookUtils.merge(PhoneBookUtils.java:510)
  at com.myapp.contacts.ContactProviderChangedService$ContactContentObserver.onChange(ContactProviderChangedService.java:80)
  at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
  at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"pool-20-thread-3" prio=5 tid=52 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x421d8f58 self=0x78d52b78
  | sysTid=26221 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2001638840
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4238e2b0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=52 (pool-20-thread-3)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"pool-20-thread-2" prio=5 tid=49 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42510560 self=0x78d24930
  | sysTid=26184 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1991618032
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4236be40> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=49 (pool-20-thread-2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AudioTrack" prio=10 tid=51 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423bada0 self=0x78435488
  | sysTid=26106 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2017677888
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 00021904  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000eec4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000ef24  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 00047a85  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread::threadLoop()+36)
  #04  pc 0000ea5d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #05  pc 0004d24d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #06  pc 0000e58f  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #07  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #08  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"pool-31-thread-1" prio=5 tid=50 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4205df18 self=0x793d9f80
  | sysTid=26095 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2034082776
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x425a6818> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=50 (pool-31-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1050)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:778)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I don't remember..It was long time ago